# Android for loop and delay not synchronous

Tags: android

**SHORT SUMMARY**

I have an activity game. User will click images:

[image: First level of game]

[image: Second level of game]

User has 5 seconds to click and to choose correct one. After 5 seconds, the correct imageview will be shown differently to draw attention and again after 5 seconds, user will see the next level.

user can click without waiting 5 seconds, so it should go immediately to next level when clicked.

I am creating view and imageviews dynamically. Imageviews are comng from local database sqlite as bytes.

My method is  creating inside oncreate method. And i use for or while loop. Each iteration is a level of game. Each level has different imageviews and different count of imageviews.

For delaying 5 + 5 seconds, i had to use handlers, threads, countdowntimers. Each one caused problems.

While using handlers, when user clicked before 5 seconds, i couldnot terminate current session.

I dont know if this is the right way.

You can see my codes below:

**LONG EXPLANATION AND CODES**

**timer:**

```
nCreate() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        imageAnswer.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                        imageAnswer.setId(R.id.imgAnswer);
                        //adding image to screen
                        finalRLayout.removeAllViews();
                        finalRLayout.addView(imageAnswer, rLayParams);

                        //starting timer, if no answer in 5 seconds, run again timer
                        startTimer();

                        //clicklisterner
                        imageAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                //if clicks true, cancel timer and go to next iteration of for loop
                                if (view == findViewById(R.id.imgAnswer)) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "clicked");
                                    //PUT IN CODE HERE TO GET NEXT IMAGE
                                    cancelTimer();

                                } else { //if not true, run again timer for last chance
                                    Log.d(TAG, "nonclick");
                                    cancelTimer();
                                    startTimer();

                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, 2000 * i);


            } //for end

        } //oncreate end

    //start timer function
    void startTimer() {
        cTimer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Log.d(TAG, "ontick");
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.d(TAG, "timer onfinish");
            }
        };
        cTimer.start();
    }


    //cancel timer
    void cancelTimer() {
        Log.d(TAG, "canceltimer");
        if (cTimer != null)
            cTimer.cancel();
    }
```

3 different thread operations but did not work. one of them made screen went into black screen. other two did not block loop's going.

```
runnable version






    for ( int i = 0; i< 20 ; i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "for i2="+ i);
            final int finalI = i;
            final RelativeLayout finalRLayout = rLayout;



            final Runnable r=new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "for finali2="+ finalI);
                    TrainingObject trainingObject = new TrainingObject();
                    trainingObject = trainingObjectList.get(finalI);
                    objectCount = 2;
//test icin
                    Log.d(TAG,"testicin trainingobjectid: "+trainingObject.getTrainingobjectID());
                    object = dbHandler.getObjectObject(trainingObject.getTrainingobjectAnswer());




                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rLayParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(140,140);

                    rLayParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                    rLayParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

                    imgBytes = object.getObjectImageBlob();
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.length);

                    imageAnswer.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    imageAnswer.setTag(trainingObject.getTrainingobjectAnswer());
                    imageAnswer.setId(R.id.imgAnswer);
                    finalRLayout.removeAllViews();
                    finalRLayout.addView(imageAnswer,rLayParams);

                }
            };
            Log.d(TAG, "3000i2 sonrasi");

            handler.postDelayed(r, 6000 * i);
            imageAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (view == findViewById(R.id.imgAnswer)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "clicked");handler.removeCallbacks(r); handler.postDelayed(r, 0);
                        //PUT IN CODE HERE TO GET NEXT IMAGE

                    }
                    else{
                        Log.d(TAG, "nonclick");
                        handler.removeCallbacks(r);  handler.postDelayed(r, 6000);

                    }
                }
            });

        }//for end
```

Comment: Are we supposed to read this question bottom-up?

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: have you tried using [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: I will send you a solution I used once to send every 5min a notification (until some condition) with an AlarmManager. This could work but I guess a 5sec delay could be manage with a simple thread. Just need to go home to access my personnal computer.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use handler to achieve your purpose, what you are supposed to do is to create a runnable and declare it outside the handler then use it by its name inside the `postDelayed` handler, and if the user clicked, just remove all handler callbacks:

```
// first create runnable
Runnable r = new Runnable{
    public void run(){
         //do what you need to do after 5 seconds
    }
}

// then create handler
Handler mHandler = new Handler();

// then in your onCreate method
nCreate() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    imageAnswer.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                    imageAnswer.setId(R.id.imgAnswer);
                    //adding image to screen
                    finalRLayout.removeAllViews();
                    finalRLayout.addView(imageAnswer, rLayParams);

                    //starting handler, if no answer in 5 seconds, run again timer
                    mHandler.postDelayed(r, 5000);

                    //clicklisterner
                    imageAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            //if clicks true, cancel timer and go to next iteration of for loop
                            if (view == findViewById(R.id.imgAnswer)) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "clicked");
                                //PUT IN CODE HERE TO GET NEXT IMAGE
                                myHandler.removeCallbacks(r);

                            } else { //if not true, run again timer for last chance
                                Log.d(TAG, "nonclick");
                                // stop the handler
                                myHandler.removeCallbacks(r);
                                // run a new one
                                mHandler.postDelayed(r, 5000);

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 2000 * i);


        } //for end

    } //oncreate end
```

Answer (score 2):

For game development you should use something more professional to implement your game, I recommend you to read this book [Beginning Android Games
2nd Edition](http://www.apress.com/9781430246770) It has the basics to 2D and 3D games with various options you could learn from. 
Now for your code I suggest you to trace the time on an external thread and make it send callbacks to an interface you implement in your main game activity 
Example :

**TimeThread.java**

```
import android.util.Log;

public class TimeThread implements Runnable {
    Thread thread = null;

    TimeTickListener listener;
    volatile boolean running = false;

    public TimeThread(TimeTickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;

    }

    public void resume() {

        thread = new Thread(this);
        running = true;
        if (thread != null)
            thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (running) {
            // sending callbacks to the mainActivity 
            listener.onTimeTick();

        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        running = false;
        while (true) {
            try {
                thread.join();
                Log.v("my", "joined ");
                break;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.v("my", "not joined cause : " + e.getMessage());

            }

        }

    }

}
```

the interface we use :

```
public interface TimeTickListener {
public void onTimeTick();
}
```

and here is an example of what the mainActivity should looks like :

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TimeTickListener {

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    // the interface  method that we implemented 
    @Override
    public void onTimeTick() {
         // keep trace of the time untill it sums up to 1 sec then do an action
         // in your situation you can make it to count 5 sec 
         // and make your action here
        if ((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000000 >= 1) {

            totalTime += 1;

            // this handler is because you should change the textView from its
            // original thread
            // and it is not allowed to be edited from another thread
            // in your case you should change the imageViews like this in the main thread 
            mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    text.setText(totalTime + " seconds passed ");
                }
            });

            startTime = System.nanoTime();

//          and this is how to terminate the thread manually (optional)
            if (totalTime >= 10) {

                timeThread.pause();
            }

        }

    }

    Handler mainHandler;
    TextView text;
    float totalTime = 0;
    TimeThread timeThread;
    TimeTickListener listener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText("wait...");
        setContentView(text);
// initializing the handler with the main activity looper 
        mainHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
//getting our implemented listener to pass it to the timeThread for the callbacks
        listener = (TimeTickListener) this;
        timeThread = new TimeThread(listener);
        // resume method will launch the thread and make it start calling the interface method (onTimeTick)
        timeThread.resume();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {      

//      don't forget to pause the thread here 
        timeThread.pause();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

This code has been tested and made a great success, the time is accurate and synced very well.

Nevertheless it is a little bit complicated and a little resource consuming because the while loop in the second thread but has so many advantages and will let you control your app correctly.

This answer is all for getting the accurate time, how to deal with time-tracing thread and where to make your action but if you have a game logic problems or hard time hiding and showing the images to the user in that case this is not the answer you want so tell me and I will try helping you.